# Testar la existencia de un fichero dinamicamente en javascript

Tags: javascript, archivo

Tengo una página web que lanza un script en background. Mientras tanto hay una página que se muestra con cierta información. Y quiero que cuando el script haya finalizado me muestra otra información en esa pagina.

Cuando lanzo el script creo un fichero `test_still_running.txt` y cuando acaba la ejecución del script lo borro. La idea es ver dinámicamente con ajax si el fichero existe y cuando deje de existir detectarlo para mostrar la información.

He intentado lo siguiente, solo que no consigo la url de mi archivo, por lo que no funciona. He intentad esto, alguna idea?

```
var url = "<?php echo json_encode(url(base_path() . "/public/test_still_running.txt")); ?>";
$.get(url)
        .done(function () {
            // exists code 
        }).fail(function () {
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ok_alert").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Estás utilizando php? Lo usas para obtener el path de tu archivo?

Comment: Estaría bien que añadieras tanto la URL que quieres generar como la que se está generando actualmente, para entender el escenario totalmente. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuando quieras para añadir más datos que consideres relevantes.

Comment: Es pregunta: ya que utilizas PHP porque no testas la existencia del fichero con PHP: `if(file_exists($tu_fichero)){...}`

Comment: porque haces eso? no crees que hay una mejor forma de bloquear la pagina, puedes bloquearla y preguntarle a un servivio via get el status de la solicitud, imagina que hay varios usuarios como vas a saber a quien lo bloqueas